# Overfull hbox with British English

Tags: line-breaking, languages, hyphenation

I write in British English and occasionally I get an overfull hbox warning because LaTeX does not know how to break a word correctly in its British form. For example, the word 'analysing' causes an overfull hbox because LaTeX will not break the word, whereas 'analyzing' is broken into 'analyz-ing' and the hbox warning goes away. what is the best solution to this? Is there a way to have LaTeX recognise British English and correctly break words?

Comment: Did you forget to load the `babel` package?  Otherwise, you will be using the default American hyphenation patterns which indeed do not break "analysing".  You see which hyphens are allowed by `\showhyphens{analysing}` etc. and add new hyphenations with the `\hyphenation` command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) with the `british` option (simply using `english` *won't* work).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american,british]{babel}

\textwidth 30pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

xxx analysing

\selectlanguage{american}

xxx analysing

\end{document}​
```

[image]

EDIT: Here's a solution in case you're using XeLaTeX/`polyglossia`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\textwidth 30pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

xxx analysing

\end{document}​
```

Comment: I did this and my biblatex-chicago package stopped working, so I loaded [american,british,english] as options for babel, which fixed it.